# Difference between function and distribution?

Tags: distributions, estimation, density-estimation, function

I have constant function as $$y = exp(-x^2)$$

This also represent gaussian distribution with mean zero and variance of 0.5 Now if we take sample from this function, which will always be from this distribution.

Now, if we **estimate the behaviour of this function by taking few sample from it and fit a curve**. Then we generally say that this is function not a distribution.

Is this because of we are not considering `mean` and `variance` while estimating?

Comment: Could you expand "Then we generally say that this is function not a distribution"? What do you mean by this?

Comment: My mean by this is by fitting a best curve, we say it function, but there are many possibilities of curves with different variance, then we use term distribution.

Comment: What do you mean by 'sample from this function'? Can you describe how this is being done?

Answer (score 5):

Small corrections and notes:

- y should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}exp(-x^2)$ to be a *density* function. This density, as you say, represents a Gaussian distribution with specific mean/variance.
- Distribution function is referred as CDF, which is the integral of the density function.

Now, let's clear the ambiguity. Sampling from a function means calculating a couple of outputs given a couple of inputs, i.e. you'll have samples like $f(x_1),f(x_2)...,f(x_n)$ given $x_1,...,x_n$. You can fit a curve to these samples and say that this is a function, yes. This is like sampling a signal, and is **unrelated** to the sampling we do in probabilistic framework.

When you create samples from distributions, you create random numbers whose **histogram** resembles the density function they're sampled from. This random number creation (*sampling*) process is often tedious. A common approach is [Inverse Transform Sampling](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Inverse_transform_sampling), which is first creating a uniform RV $u$ (between 0,1), which is another problem, and applying $F^{-1}(u)$, where $F(x)$ is CDF of the random variable we're interested in. For creating Gauss RV, there is [Box-Muller](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) method.

To sum up, sampling from a distribution is like making up a histogram, other than plotting $y$ curve.